# Code publish to folder not copying EmailTemplate folder .NET 6

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

I have upgraded my Web API project from ASP.NET Framework to .NET 6. We were using the publish to folder option before publishing the code to IIS directory and it was copying EmailTemplate folder fine which has html files for emails. But as we upgraded to .NET6 the EmailTemplate folder is not copied and I have to manually copy/paste it every time. Anyone else faced the same issue or any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: did you publish using git or normal publish ?, check the git ignore where the EmailTemplate folder is added

Comment: share your project file. did you added that folder as link or reference to your project ?

Comment: @Karthikcbe No, its not in gitignore file.

Comment: Try this example, it uses the ResolvedFileToPublish item, whose default behavior is to always copy the files provided in the Include attribute to the published site. Override the default behavior by including a <CopyToPublishDirectory> child element with inner text of either Never or PreserveNewest<ResolvedFileToPublish Include="..\ReadMe2.md">
  <RelativePath>wwwroot\ReadMe2.md</RelativePath>
  <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
</ResolvedFileToPublish>

Comment: For more info follow this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 0):

I have added this to my project file and copied it to the folder.

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="EmailTemplates\**">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```